# How to record and save macros or regex in spacemacs

Tags: regex, emacs, macros, spacemacs

I want to reuse a series of regular expression replacements regularly.  In plain emacs, I would record a keyboard macro, but entering the much more useful regular expressions provided by spacemacs, the recording stops automatically after the first replacement step.  How can I do this, and do more general macro recording?  Also, are the two recording mechanisms (the emacs and the vim one) implemented the same under the hood, or do they coexist?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't use `vim` tags for `spacemacs` questions; it's just emulating some Vim keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Show a step-by-step recipe of what you tried. The question is unclear, so far. A keyboard macro just records keys you press (and menu items you use). We cannot guess how you tried to enter a regexp etc. Show exactly what you did in Emacs.